# Google Maps Api: cannot click on clickable polygon behind datalayer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-datalayer

Hi I am using google maps api(JavaScript) to build an interactive world map. It went really well until I ran into this problem. I am using polygons to show to outline of a country. These polygons trigger a modal showing information about the  country when clicked on. This worked until I started to use "Data Layer: Earthquake data". Instead of using earthquake data I use sales information of the company I work at. So if a large share of our customers are from the Netherlands then the datalayer assigned to the Netherlands will be very large. The problem is that because of the datalayers the countries are no longer clickable. I can not click "through" the datalayer. Is there a possibility that I can trigger the event behind the datalayer?

This code displays the datalayers:

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('./data/test.json');

map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var percentage = parseFloat(feature.getProperty('percentage'));
  return ({
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: percentage,
      fillColor: '#00ff00',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      strokeWeight: 0
    }
  })

});

map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
    title: 'Hello, World!'
  });
});

map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  map.data.revertStyle();
});

function eqfeed_callback(data) {
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}
```

This code displays the polygons:

```
function drawMap(data) {

  var rows = data['rows'];
  for (var i in rows) {
    if (rows[i][0] != 'Antarctica') {


      var newCoordinates = [];
      var geometries = rows[i][1]['geometries'];

      if (geometries) {
        for (var j in geometries) {
          newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
        }
      } else {
        newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
      }
      var country = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: newCoordinates,
        strokeColor: 'transparent',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 0.3,
        fillColor: '#cd0000',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        name: rows[i][0]

      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          fillOpacity: 0.3
        });
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          fillOpacity: 0
        });
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'click', function() {
        var countryName = this.name;
        var code = convert(countryName); // Calls a function that converts the name of the country to its official ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code.
        var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
        var instance = M.Modal.init(modal);
        instance.open();

      });


      country.setMap(map);
    }
  }
```

If read in the documentation that changing the zIndex won't work because "Markers are always displayed in front of line-strings and polygons."

Is there a way to click on a polygon behind a datalayer?

**EDIT**
I tried to give the polygon a higher zIndex and I made the datalayer not clickable

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('./data/test.json');

map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var percentage = parseFloat(feature.getProperty('percentage'));

  return ({
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: percentage,
      fillColor: '#00ff00',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      clickAble: false,
      zIndex: 50


    }
  })

});

function eqfeed_callback(data) {
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}


function drawMap(data) {

  var rows = data['rows'];
  for (var i in rows) {
    if (rows[i][0] != 'Antarctica') {


      var newCoordinates = [];
      var geometries = rows[i][1]['geometries'];

      if (geometries) {
        for (var j in geometries) {
          newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
        }
      } else {
        newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
      }
      var country = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: newCoordinates,
        strokeColor: 'transparent',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 0.3,
        fillColor: '#cd0000',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        name: rows[i][0],
        zIndex: 100

      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          fillOpacity: 0.3
        });
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          fillOpacity: 0
        });
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'click', function() {
        var countryName = this.name;
        var code = convert(countryName); // Calls a function that converts the name of the country to its official ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code.
        var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
        var instance = M.Modal.init(modal);
        instance.open();

      });


      country.setMap(map);
    }
  }
  //console.log(map);
  //test(map)
}
```

**EDIT**
Apparently the datalayer wasn't the problem, but the icon was. That is why it didn't work when I did this:

```
     map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        var percentage = parseFloat(feature.getProperty('percentage'));

        return ({
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: percentage,
                fillColor: '#00ff00',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                strokeWeight: 0,
                clickable: false
            }

        })

    });
```

The correct way to do it is this:

```
    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        var percentage = parseFloat(feature.getProperty('percentage'));

        return ({
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: percentage,
                fillColor: '#00ff00',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                strokeWeight: 0
            },
            clickable: false
        })

    });
```

Comment: Did you try the `zIndex`? Setting it to `1` on the Polygon places it in front of the data layer.

Comment: 1) you have a typo it should be `clickable` and not `clickAble` and 2) what doesn't work now?

Comment: See my updated answer with full working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have 2 options here:

1. Set the `zIndex` of your Polygons to a higher number than the data layer. Your Polygons will be clickable but obviously will appear above the data layer, which might not be what you want.
2. Set the `clickable` property of the data layer to false so that you can click elements that are below. This will work *if* you don't need to react to clicks on the data layer...

Option 2 example code:

```
map.data.setStyle({
    clickable: false
});
```

**Edit:** Full working example below, using option 2. As you can see the Polygon is below the data layer but you can still click it.

```js
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137
    }
  });

  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    paths: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(-26, 139),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23, 130),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 130),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-26, 139)
    ],
    map: map
  });

  polygon.addListener('click', function() {

    console.log('clicked on polygon');
  });

  // Load GeoJSON
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');

 // Set style
  map.data.setStyle({
    fillColor: '#fff',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    clickable: false
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Did you really? The code you linked to doesn't contain any of what I suggested in my answer: no z-index and no clickable property. Update **your question** with the code you used (don't just share a link).

Answer (score 2):

I have found that after, setting the z-order, the maps api does not reliably send clicks to polygon feature in the top layer when there are many polygons.

I had one data layer of regions where each feature is a precinct boundary. When you click on one feature, it loads another data layer on top. The top layer consists of polygons inside the region with a higher z-order, representing house title boundaries within that region.

After the houses are loaded, clicking on a house should send the click to the house polygon, not the region. But this sometimes failed - especially if there are many houses.

To resolve the issue, after clicking on a region feature, I set that feature to be non clickable. Then the clicks always propagate to the correct house feature. You can still click on other features of the lower layer, just not the selected one. This solution should work if your data and presentation follows a similar pattern.

```js
/* private utility is only called by this.hideOnlyMatchingFeaturesFromLayer() */
  _overrideStyleOnFeature(feature, layer, key, value,  overrideStyle, defaultStyle) {
    if (feature.getProperty(key) === value) {
      if (this.map) {
        layer.overrideStyle(feature, overrideStyle);
      }
    } else {
      if (this.map) {
        layer.overrideStyle(feature, defaultStyle);
      }
    }
  }

  /* Apply an overrideStyle style to features in a data layer that match key==value
   * All non-matching features will have the default style applied.
   * Otherwise all features except the matching feature is hidden!
   * Examples:
   *    overrideStyle = { clickable: false,strokeWeight: 3}
   *    defaultStyle = { clickable: true,strokeWeight: 1}
   */

  overrideStyleOnMatchingFeaturesInLayer(layer, key, value, overrideStyle, defaultStyle) {
    layer.forEach((feature) => {
      if (Array.isArray(feature)) {
        feature.forEach((f) => {
          _overrideStyleOnFeature(f, layer, key, value, overrideStyle, defaultStyle);
        });
      } else {
        _overrideStyleOnFeature(feature, layer, key, value, overrideStyle, defaultStyle);
      }
    });
  }

  /* example usage */
  overrideStyleOnMatchingFeaturesInLayer(
    theRegionsDataLayer,
    'PROP_NAME',
    propValue,
    { clickable: false, strokeWeight: 3},
    { clickable: true, strokeWeight: 1}
);
```